# Chrome Browser freezes on undocking

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, laptop, freeze

I'm running Chrome 38 on Windows 7 Pro on a Lenovo Thinkpad W530. Chrome seems stable most of the time, but whenever I undock or dock from my docking station, I run the risk that Chrome will become completely unresponsive. I should note that the laptop lid is closed when I dock, and open when undocked.

Any ideas as to why Chrome frequently doesn't survive this transition?

Comment: I found this discussion that suggested it might be an issue with hardware rendering and the dual GPU, but turning off hardware rendering didn't seem to help.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ZUr06oCmNfw

Comment: To me it also sometimes happens when recovering from sleep/hibernate - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156038

Answer (score 2):

I turned off "Use hardware acceleration when available" in Chrome's Advanced settings and I was able to un-dock and re-dock without it hanging up.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `chrome://crashes` which will show you information regarding Chrome crashes. This log will help you try to identify the key to this problem.

To pinpoint the issue, try doing all/some of these things:

### Disable Conflicting Modules

Open `chrome://conflicts` and see whether there are any conflicting modules detected. If there are, then either update them or uninstall them.

### Disable Extensions

Open `chrome://extensions` and uncheck the "Enabled" checkboxes for about every extension.

### Delete User Data

Make sure Windows Explorer can view hidden files, folders and drives. Next, go to `C:\Users\your_username_here\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`, select all and delete them. These files are browser settings and Chrome will rebuild them again.

### Disable Software Rendering

Open Internet Properties, go to the Advanced tab and uncheck "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering" under "Accelerated graphics".

At the end of the day, if neither of these work try reinstalling Chrome.